Arduino ESP32-S2 TCP packet size
I am using ESP32-S2 in Arduino IDE as TCP/IP server.
how can i change the TCP data receive packet size ?
it is currently 5760 bytes,  I have seen  this in Wireshark TCP SYN packet ?
I have tried changing config parameters in sdkconfig file, but didn't worked out.

What are you actually trying to accomplish here? The "maximum packet size" (MTU) is determined by the network medium - WiFi, ethernet, etc. WiFi's MTU is  2304 but the usable MTU is less than that due to some space being used for encryption information. So a "maximum receive packet size" for TCP of 5760 makes no sense.

I am trying to get the maximum throughput  in TCP/IP communication. I understand that the MTU is determined by the network medium. However the receive buffer size can be configured within the device.  The receive buffer size  is shared as window size  during TCP initial communication.

The Arduino environment for ESP32 works on compiled configuration of ESP IDF framework. So, its not possible to change any ESP32 configuration in Arduino IDE.
There are 2 options to Change the configuration parameters.

Change the configuration in ESP IDF CMD terminal and copy the compiled object files to the Arduino library (it has problem, when version mismatch happens).

Use Espressif IDE for the development instead of Arduino IDE.(Configuration is quite simple )


